# How to get results from 2 queries as 1 output in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit new to MySQL, and had a look around on other answers, but couldn't get this working to what i need:
im using it thru mysqli in PHP

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
  temp_table ( INDEX(ps_inv_id) ) 
AS (
 SELECT ps_inv_id,ps_custom_fields,ps_item_id,ps_member,ps_name,ps_active 
  FROM purchase_check  
  WHERE purchase_check.ps_member = '63' AND purchase_check.ps_active ='1' )UNION
  SELECT * 
  FROM temp_table   
  WHERE  ps_inv_id IN (SELECT MIN(ps_inv_id) FROM temp_table GROUP BY ps_name);
```

I might be wrong in trying to use UNION, but i will try to explain what i need to do:

now an explanation of the table:

- ps_active can be only 0 or 1;
- ps_name can differ according to product
- ps_member, depending on member who's product it is
- ps_item_id,    according to product, can be any of up to 50 products
- ps_custom_fields, also product related
- ps_inv_id, 1 unique id /    transaction

my aim is:for the member i am querying,i want to pull all his current active products,but there might be more than one of the same, in which case, i only want the lower invoice id of the same products

```
ps_inv_id   ps_custom_fields    ps_item_id  ps_member       ps_name     ps_active   G_name  
37          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       54  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     0       BP
142         {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       54  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP 1       BP
45          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       55  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
115         {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       56  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
53          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       57  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     0       BP
44          {"1":"2"}               1       59  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     0       BP
124         {"1":"1<2+1 bases>"}    1       59  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP 1       BP
25          {"1":"2"}               19      63  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual UC  0       BP
120         {"1":"7"}               1       63  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP 0       BP
123         {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       63  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP 1       BP
122         {"1":"5<2+5 bases>"}    1       63  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP 1       BP
38          {"1":"1<2+1 bases>"}    1       65  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
113         {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       67  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
51          {"1":"2<2+2 bases>"}    1       68  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
101         {"1":"1<2+1 bases>"}    1       69  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
56          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       70  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
55          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       74  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
26          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       75  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     0       BP
39          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       76  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     0       BP
94          {"1":"2"}               1       77  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     0       BP
98          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       77  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
22          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       78  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
42          {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       79  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
57          {"1":"1<2+1 bases>"}    1       80  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     0       BP
86          {"1":"1<2+1 bases>"}    1       80  INNOVATIVE Elite Casual     1       BP
```

so, i basically want to do:

```
SELECT ps_inv_id,ps_custom_fields,ps_item_id,ps_member,ps_name,ps_active 
  FROM purchase_check  
  WHERE purchase_check.ps_member = '63' AND purchase_check.ps_active ='1'
```

get its result:

```
ps_inv_id   ps_custom_fields    ps_item_id  ps_member   ps_name                     ps_active   
123         {"1":"0<2+0 bases>"}    1       63          INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP     1
122         {"1":"5<2+5 bases>"}    1       63          INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP     1
```

This member,63, had only one active product type,1,, but 2 of the same products according to invoices,inv 122 and 123, i only want the first of the 2,nr 122, if there were more product types active for this user, i would have wanted one invoice for each product type for that member.

put them into an temporary table, then from the temporary table, i want to:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM temp_table   
  WHERE  ps_inv_id IN (SELECT MIN(ps_inv_id) FROM temp_table GROUP BY ps_name)
```

to give me 1 result only:

```
122         {"1":"5<2+5 bases>"}    1       63          INNOVATIVE Elite Casual-VIP     1
```

But all as one query, as i attempted in the beginning.

As for a MCVE..this is as complete as i can get it, i can add more explanation if required, but, with the code and examples, i think it is clear.

EDIT:
If i use it as 3 separate queries:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table (INDEX(ps_inv_id) )AS 
SELECT ps_inv_id,ps_custom_fields,ps_item_id,ps_member,ps_name,ps_active FROM purchase_check WHERE purchase_check.ps_member = '63' AND purchase_check.ps_active ='1';


 SELECT * 
  FROM temp_table   
  WHERE  ps_inv_id IN (SELECT MIN(ps_inv_id) FROM temp_table GROUP BY ps_name);


DROP TABLE temp_table  ;
```

Then it works fine, but the table is not as a temp table in the memory...
once i change it to CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE, it tells me temp_table do not exist...

So for now, its the closest to a working answer i have

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: had a look, added more explanations

Comment: Well, it was just a suggestion. Never mind then.